# How to pass a component to all pages except one next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a layout component which I want to pass to all the pages except the `authenticate` page.

I have tried using `Component.name` which works for dev but not for production version.

How can I do this?

```
  if (Component.name === 'Authenticate') {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Authenticate>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </Authenticate>
    </Provider>
  );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js Opt out of Layout Component for specific pages from \_app.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66914855/next-js-opt-out-of-layout-component-for-specific-pages-from-app-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `useRouter` inside `_app.js` (recommended)

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {asPath,route,pathname } = router // pick the one that you need
  
  if(asPath === "Authenticate"){
     return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
     )
  }else{
     return(
       <Provider store={store}>
          <Authenticate>
            <Layout>
               <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
        </Authenticate>
      </Provider>
     )
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can apply the same logic directly inside `<Authenticate>` component, and if the current route is "Authenticate" just return the childrens.

Another solution could be to use `getInitialProps`,  but in this way CSR will be disabled and you will rely on the request instead of  next.js router:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   const {path } = pageProps 
  
   if(path === "Authenticate"){
      return (
         <Provider store={store}>
           <Component {...pageProps} />
         </Provider>
      )
   }else{
      return(
        <Provider store={store}>
           <Authenticate>
             <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
             </Layout>
         </Authenticate>
       </Provider>
      )
   }
}
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => { 
  return {pageProps : {
    path : appContext.ctx.pathname
  }}
}
```