# How to remove Header from a single page in NextJS Layout?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am working on a NextJS project using Layout so that I can use the same Header and Footer for all pages. But for one of the pages, I don't need the Header, I need the Footer alone. Is there any way to do this?

This is my _App.js:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

This is how I am rendering them:

```
  <Header />
  <SidebarMenu />
  <FloatingChat />

  {/* Display props */}
  {children}

  <Footer />
```

Comment: You can create a separate components such as `<Header />` and `<Footer />` and call one or both of them as you want. Or, if you want to dig deeper, build your own `_document.tsx` file, [read here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js Opt out of Layout Component for specific pages from \_app.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66914855/next-js-opt-out-of-layout-component-for-specific-pages-from-app-js)

Comment: @ShreyasJadhav yes, it does..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [next/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)'s pathname property to get the page it's currently on, and then not render the Header if the page is a non-header page.

Answer (score 13):

I know it's been 3 months but I still wanna answer this cause me being a beginner faced difficulties when they only link documentation which are generally really vague.

Considering this is your layout.jsx

```
  <Header />
  <SidebarMenu />
  <FloatingChat />
  {children}
  <Footer />
```

you can use `next/router` to show or hide the components

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import SidebarMenu from "./SidebarMenu";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Layout({children}){
    const router = useRouter();
    if(router.pathname != "/pagename" )
    return (
         <Header />
         <SidebarMenu />
         <FloatingChat />
         {children}
         <Footer />
    )
    else {
        return (
         <SidebarMenu />
         <FloatingChat />
         {children}
        )
    }
}
```

We just tell the layout.jsx file to show the specific layout on not that page and everywhere else and if it does come on that page we can show a different layout also you can next the pathnames if you want it on multiple pages.

Comment: May need updating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74421327/nextrouter-was-not-mounted-next-js

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
const pathname = usePathname();

...
if(pathname != "/pagename" )
...