# How to do dynamic routes with nextjs 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

How do we do dynamic routing with layouts in nextjs 13?

I have a directory in the new next pages app in which im trying to do dynamic routing: `app/dashboard/[id].jsx`, however it does not work with the dashboard layout.

How do I do it? Normal pages work like `app/dashboard/pages.jsx` but how do we do dynamic routes in which i can also get the id?

Comment: did you try to do `app/dashboard/[id]/page.jsx` ?

Comment: How to do this in api directory? doesn't work there

Answer (score 26):

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page

So: `app/dashboard/[id]/page.jsx`

Your `Page` function can take a `params` argument:

```
export default function Page({ params, searchParams }) {
    return <div>ID: {params.id}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 21):

In the latest `App Router` of Nextjs `13.4`, It can be done in the following way.

**Summary**

1. single param (`blog/123`)

   - Use: `[blogId]`
2. multiple params (`blog/a/b`)

   - Use: `[...blogId]`
3. optional params (`blog/` or `blog/a`)

   - Use: `[[...blogId]]`

### [image]

###### ⚠ Caution : You cannot use both optional params and multiple params at the same time

---

#### Invoking

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
            <Link href={"/blog/123"} className="bg-green-400 w-fit rounded-lg p-4">
                Single param
            </Link>
            <Link href={"blog/a/b"} className="bg-blue-400 w-fit rounded-lg p-4">
                Multiple Params
            </Link>
            <Link href={"blog"} className="bg-amber-400 w-fit rounded-lg p-4">
                Optional
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
}
```

#### Receiving

1. ##### Single parameter

   ```
   export default function BlogPost({ params }: { params: { blogId: string } }) {
    return <h1>{params.blogId}</h1>;
   }
   ```
2. ##### Multiple Parameters

   ```
   export default function BlogPost({ params }: { params: { blogId: string[] } }) {
    console.log(params);
    return (
        <div className="">
            {params.blogId[0]}
            {params.blogId[1]}
        </div>
     );
   }
   ```

*Also refer latest Nextjs 13 code templates*
[**Next.js 13+ Power Snippets | TypeScript/Javascript**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krishnaacharyaa.nextjs-13-power-snippets)

*It includes wide range of code snippets for both `ts` and `js`. Find all snippets* [**here**](https://github.com/krishnaacharyaa/nextjs-13-power-snippets/blob/HEAD/documentation/snippets.md)

---

**Useful Links:**

- [Get URL Params (Next.js 13)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613628/13431819)
- [Nexjs Dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the getLayout function to define a custom layout for a page, including dynamic routes. Here's an example of how you can use `getLayout` to apply the `DashboardLayout` to all pages under the `/dashboard` route:

Define your custom DashboardLayout component:

```js
     import React from 'react';
     import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
 
     const DashboardLayout = ({ children }) => {
       return (
     <>
       <Navbar />
       <main>{children}</main>
     </>
   );
 };
 
 export default DashboardLayout;
```

In your dynamic route file `(pages/dashboard/[id].jsx)`, define the getLayout function to return the `DashboardLayout`:

```js
    
   import DashboardLayout from '../../layouts/DashboardLayout';
    
    const DashboardPage = ({ id }) => {
      return <h1>Dashboard page with ID: {id}</h1>;
    };
    
    DashboardPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
      return <DashboardLayout>{page}</DashboardLayout>;
    };
    
    export default DashboardPage;
```

Note that the `getLayout` function takes in the page as an argument, representing the page component wrapped with the layout. You can then return the `DashboardLayout` component with the page as its child.

To extract the id parameter from the URL, you can use the `useRouter` hook from the `next/router` module:

```js
   import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
   import DashboardLayout from '../../layouts/DashboardLayout';
    
    const DashboardPage = () => {
      const router = useRouter();
      const { id } = router.query;
    
      return <h1>Dashboard page with ID: {id}</h1>;
    };
    
    DashboardPage.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
      return <DashboardLayout>{page}</DashboardLayout>;
    };
    
    export default DashboardPage;
```

In this example, we use the `useRouter` hook to access the query object containing the dynamic route parameters. We can then extract the id parameter from the query object and use it in our component.

With these changes, your dynamic route should now use the `DashboardLayout` component.

Answer (score 0):

use this below approach and this worked for me.

```
app/dashboard/[id]/page.jsx
```