# Get URL Params (Next.js 13)

Tags: reactjs, url, next.js

I am building a Next.js 13 project with the `/app` directory. I have a problem - in the root layout, I have a permanent navbar component in which the component is imported from `/components/Navbar.jsx`. Basically inside the `Navbar.jsx`, I want to be able to access the slug parameter in url, for ex: `localhost:3000/:slug` in which I want the slug id. I have already defined a Next.js 13 page.jsx for that slug. But how do I get the slug id in the **navbar** component. I also don't want to use `window.location.pathname` because it doesn't change when the page routes to a different slug and only does when I refresh.

I have tried the old Next.js 12 method:

```js
//components/navbar.jsx;

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Navbar () {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(slug);
  }, []);

  return <p>Slug: {slug}</p>
}
```

However it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get (query string) parameters from the URL in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862600/how-can-i-get-query-string-parameters-from-the-url-in-next-js)

Answer (score 25):

To get the URL parameters in a Server Component in **Next.js 13**, you can use the `searchParams` argument of the Page function.

*URL*

```
localhost:3000/?slug
```

*/app/page.js*

```
export default function Page({searchParams}) {
   return <Navbar slug={searchParams}></Navbar>
}
```

*navbar.js*

```
export default function Navbar(props) {
   return <p>Slug: {props.slug}</p>
}
```

More info: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page

Comment: How can we type this?

Comment: For route.js, use req.nextUrl.searchParams. The req is a NextRequest object that is past as the first parameter to for example the GET function ie 

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {

Answer (score 25):

##### There are 3 different variants of params

1. params  `(/blog/1)`

   - single params
   - multiple params
2. searchParams `(/blog?postId=123)`

   - single search params
   - multiple search params
3. Both params and searchParams `(/blog/1?postId=123)`

---

##### There are multiple ways to handle this

1. For params - [`useParams()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-params)

```
'use client'
 
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const params = useParams()
 
  // Route -> /shop/[tag]/[item]
  // URL -> /shop/shoes/nike-air-max-97
  // `params` -> { tag: 'shoes', item: 'nike-air-max-97' }
  console.log(params)
 
  return <></>
}
```

2. For searchParams - [`useSearchParams()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params)

```
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?search=my-project`
  // `search` -> 'my-project'
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}
```

3. Both params and search Params using `any` type

```
'use client'

export default function BlogPost(props: any) {

    // URL -> blog/a/b?param1=IamfirstParam&param2=IamsecondParam
    return <div>{props}</div>;

   // Output ->
   //{
   //  params: { blogId: [ 'a', 'b' ] },
   //  searchParams: { param1: 'IamfirstParam', param2: 'IamsecondParam' }
   //}
}
```

4. Both params and search Params using `defined` type

```
'use client';

// URL -> blog/a/b?param1=IamfirstParam&param2=IamsecondParam

export default function BlogPost({
    params,
    searchParams,
}: {
    params: { blogId: string[] };
    searchParams: { param1: string; param2: string };
}) {


    return (
        <div>
            {params.blogId[0]}
            {params.blogId[1]}
            {searchParams.param1}
            {searchParams.param2}
        </div>
    );
}
```

For all possibility of dynamic params refer: [How to do dynamic routes with Next.js 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609568/13431819)

---

*Also refer to the latest Next.js 13 code templates*
[**Next.js 13+ Power Snippets | TypeScript/Javascript**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krishnaacharyaa.nextjs-13-power-snippets)

*It includes wide range of code snippets for both `ts` and `js`. Find all snippets* [**here**](https://github.com/krishnaacharyaa/nextjs-13-power-snippets/blob/HEAD/documentation/snippets.md)

Comment: It's not necessary to only do all of this from **client components.** We can still reap the benefits of **server components** in any [`page` file.](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page)

Answer (score 13):

Another way is to use the hook `useSearchParams`.

From the [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-search-params):

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Page() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  // E.g. `/dashboard?page=2&order=asc`
  const page = searchParams.get('page');
  const order = searchParams.get('order');

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Page: {page}</p>
      <p>Order: {order}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: useSearchParams requires client side component, it doesn't work in server side component

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, I was looking for a client sided get param. <3

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if the question is still relevant but you can use `NextRequest` included methods `nextUrl.searchParams.get` or `getAll` if it's an array.

```js
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  
  const queryParam = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("queryParam");
  
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Query parameter value is ' + queryParam }, { status: 200 });
}
```

I used it in an endpoint but the same goes for pages, must warn that `NextRequest` can only be used in server components, for client ones you need `useRouter` with the `'use client'`.

Answer (score 6):

In order to get `params` and `searchParams` in server side component using typescript in Next.js 13, you should define what params and searchParams do you expect. For example:

```js
// /app/category/[slug]/page.tsx
// Request URL localhost:3000/category/news?page=2

export default function PostsCategory({ params, searchParams }: { params: { slug: string }; searchParams: { page: string } }) {
  const posts = getPostsByTag(params.slug, ['title', 'date', 'excerpt', 'image', 'slug', 'tags']);
  const currentPage = searchParams && searchParams.page ? Number(searchParams.page) : 1;
  const { slug } = params;

  return (
    <main>
      <PaginatedPosts posts={posts} page={currentPage} title={`${slug}`} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I feel like this is a pretty common use-case yet it's pretty hard to find in the current Next.js docs if you don't know to search for `searchParams` (ironically).

Comment: How about layouts? The question is about the layout and its components?

Comment: @mmomtchev But why would you even need to check for searchParams in layout as the layout applies to everything underlying. In my opinion if you are using the same search params down the structure then you have something wrong in app architecture of app. For example (?param=1, /blog?param=1, /blog/post?param1), this doesn't make much sense, each page has or [slug] page have unique set of params.

Comment: @mmomtchev and same goes for components (reusable part of the code), you don't know which page they will belong to (yes, you may know it and use it only on one place but for example Pagination component should not be owner of data, it should handle page changes and relevant calls but to make it reusable data has to come from top of hierarchy - in this case page)

Comment: You didn't see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Had to use `usePathname`

```
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
```

Answer (score 2):

The official docs are very clear on this: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#server-components

**Pages**

To access search params in Pages (Server Components), use the `searchParams` prop.

**Layouts**

Unlike Pages, Layouts (Server Components) do not receive the `searchParams` prop. This is because a shared layout is not re-rendered during navigation which could lead to stale `searchParams` between navigations.

Instead, use the Page `searchParams` prop or the `useSearchParams` hook in a Client Component, which is re-rendered on the client with the latest `searchParams`.

*So simply make a small client component that will be re-rendered at every navigation and reference it from your layout.*

Comment: Precisely. Or, restructure such that you can just get this in a `page`.

Answer (score 0):

- If your Navbar is a server component, you can try to pass params from the parent component. In Nextjs 13, Page and Layout will have a params field in props that indicates params of URL. You can have a look at this [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page). Example:

  ```js
  export default async function Page({params}) {
        const { slug } = params;

    return <Navbar slug={slug} />
  }

  export default async function Navbar ({ slug }) {
    return <p>Slug: {slug}</p>
  }
  ```
- If you use any hook like useParams hook. The component will become a client component at runtime.