# Dynamic Links are not passing props redirected components while routing in nextjs13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm learning nextjs using [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086RD8JVW) "Building React Apps using server-side rendering"

In this I'm building basic react app with index page link to about page.

The project `package.json` -

```json
{
  "name": "my-next-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "next",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.4.19",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

`pages/index.js` is -

```js
import React from "react";
import GetLink from "../sharedComponents/DynamicRouter";

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello from Next.js</p>
      <GetLink title='Page 1'></GetLink>
      <GetLink title='Page 2'></GetLink>
      <GetLink title='Page 3'></GetLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

`sharedComponents/DynamicRouter.js` is -

```js
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

function GetLink(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={`/SecondPage?content=${props.title}`}>{props.title}</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`pages/SecondPage.js` is -

```js
export default (props) => {

  console.log(JSON.stringify(props));

  return (
  <h1>
    Welcome to {props.url.query.content}
  </h1>
)};
```

The `console.log` prints `{}` in the console.

In the browser I'm getting error.

[image]

What I would like to see is `Welcome to Page 1`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `pages/SecondPage.js` is incorrect, because you are not receiving any `props` to it (which is why the `console.log` is `{}`). So `props.url` is `undefined`. Hence the error you are seeing.

If your use-case to display the `content` query param, you can do like this:

```
export default () => {
  const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const content = query.get('content');

  return (
    <h1>
      Welcome to {content}
    </h1>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just that you are confused with terms, let me explain

1. `params`

   These are of type `route/:id` => Here `id` is **param**
2. `searchParams`

   These are of type `route?id`  => Here id is **searchParam**
3. `param` & `searchParams`

   These includes both `route/:id1?id2` => Here id1 is **param** & id2 is **searchParam**
   ``

---

So basically what you are trying to do is, pass `searchParam` and looking for `param`

**Solution** ,

1. Either pass it as `params`

   ```
   <Link href={`/SecondPage/${props.title}`}>{props.title}</Link>
   ```
2. Or Receive it as `searchParam`

   ```
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const content = query.get('content');
   ```

To further understand follow the below links

- [Get URL Params (Next.js 13)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76613628/13431819)
- [How to do dynamic routes with nextjs 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609568/13431819)
- [How can I get (query string) parameters from the URL in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76660467/13431819)

---

Also refer latest Nextjs 13 code templates
[**Next.js 13+ Power Snippets | TypeScript/Javascript**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krishnaacharyaa.nextjs-13-power-snippets)

It includes wide range of code snippets for both `ts` and `js`. Find all snippets [**here**](https://github.com/krishnaacharyaa/nextjs-13-power-snippets/blob/HEAD/documentation/snippets.md)