# Next.js throwing Error: Error: NextRouter was not mounted when using _document.js inside pages folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to be able to customize the HTML based on the current locale. I have created a `_document.js` inside `pages` directory. And I used this code:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Document() {
  
  const { locale } = useRouter();

  return (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

When I go to the URL specified, I see them saying that I'm using logic outside `<Main />`. Thus, how can I access `locale` inside `_document.js`?

I found [NextRouter was not mounted Next.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74421327/nextrouter-was-not-mounted-next-js) but even using `next/navigation` did not work for me, and I get this error:

> Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted

Answer (score 9):

It happened to me in the client component of `app` directory.

Instead of this

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
```

import from

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
```

Answer (score 3):

`useRouter()` hook runs on the browser while [`_document.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) runs on the server; that's the problem. For example, if you add a `console.log('Hello Word')` in `Document` before the `return`, it gets printed only in your development server, not on the browser.

You shouldn't be trying to use a logic related to hooks in `_document.js`, as it's not meant for, as the doc says:

> React components outside of `<Main />` will not be initialized by the browser. Do not add application logic here or custom CSS (like styled-jsx). If you need shared components in all your pages (like a menu or a toolbar), read [Layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts) instead.